# PCA953X compiled-in driver

Tags: command-line, drivers, kernel

I have small/strange PC x86 with ordinary 22.04 ubuntu on it.
This pc has SMBus which is based on i2c bus.
And I have two additional chips TCA6804 ( gpio_pca953x driver) and LTC2945 ( ltc2945 driver ).

And here I have THE question. How the **** can I convince Ubuntu , that I have such devices connected ?

I can see both using i2cdetect -y 0.
I can load drivers , but something is still missing.
Like Device tree definition or acpi ....

But there is no device tree in my system.
Does anybody know how to get it running properly ?

Solution like :

$ sudo modprobe ltc2945
$ sudo echo ltc2945 0x10 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device

return permision denied

I miss something obiouse or extremally difficult.

Specially when I see that one of this drivers gets value from somwhere:

*if (device_property_read_u32(dev, "shunt-resistor-micro-ohms",
&data->shunt_resistor))*

Best regards

Adam Górski

Comment: Your `$ sudo echo ltc2945 0x10 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device` FAILS because redirection (`> /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device`) is set up (or not) by the unprivileged parent process, AND you have the `sudo` in the wrong place. `echo` doesn't benefit from UID 0. Instead, `echo "ltc2945 0x10" | sudo tee /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device` will do what you're trying.